# python dictionary key error excel

Tags: python, pandas, geopy

I'm sure I'm doing something rather silly, but I'm just not seeing it!

Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
import pandas as pd
geo_dic = pd.read_excel('cityzip.xlsx', index_col=0).to_dict()

print geo_dic[' Longitude']['601'][0]
```

cityzip.xlsx contains these rows (and many more):

```
Postal   Latitude    Longitude
601      18.1786    -66.7518
```

I receive "KeyError: '601'" every time.

Eventually, I'd like to use geopy to calculate and write the zipcodes distances from a set of city coordinates into the xlsx file, so any tips or resources for the next steps are appreciated too!

Comment: It's hard to tell without a bit more info on what `geo_dic` looks like. Could you add what `geo_dic.head()` returns?

Comment: 'print geo_dic.head()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'head''

Comment: Sorry I misread that, I meant run that of the dataframe before converting to a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Just try printing geo_dict['Longitude'][601]

Access 601 as integer, not as string

I don't think [0] is required.

Comment: @TylerHudson-Crimi My pleasure!! if it is working for you, can you please accept this as an answer?